# Issue with xmpp - message archiving management time span

Tags: ios, openfire, xmppframework

I am using openfire 4.2.0 and monitoring plugin 1.6.0 for xmpp chat.

for fetching chat history via XEP-0313 [MAM]

I am using following stanza for query.

```
<iq type="set" id="dev69">
<query
    xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="0D57123A-6B7D-47AF-9EED-4E6870FD9615">
    <x
        xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
        <field var="start">
            <value>2018-07-12T07:05:08.008Z</value>
        </field>
        <field var="end">
            <value>2018-07-12T07:06:40.040Z</value>
        </field>
        <field var="with">
            <value>dev60@dev.myapp.com</value>
        </field>
        <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
            <value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value>
        </field>
    </x>
</query>
```

And following is the response I got :

```
<message
xmlns="jabber:client" to="dev69@dev.myapp.com/19tjt2y06i">
<result
    xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="C1B078F6-829C-474B-8F8A-59C1236AD69C" id="965">
    <forwarded
        xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
        <delay
            xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="2018-07-12T06:15:07.985Z">
        </delay>
        <message
            xmlns="jabber:client" type="chat" id="87AF91F4-E425-4103-9B71-29AD1ECD1ADD" to="dev60@dev.myapp.com" from="dev69@dev.myapp.com/z9g06o63v">
            <body>A</body>
        </message>
    </forwarded>
</result>
```

**MY ISSUE :-**

As you can see the forwarded message I got in response has the time stamp way before the start time of the query stanza. even though I am using correct time format as specified in the docs. I still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: sorry can you explain a little more and why you are using delay for mam ?

Comment: I am not using delay. its just the response I got from openfire'

Comment: please show the output packet that you are sending